# Adding A Like Button To IOS App but not a facebook one

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform

My data Is Held on parse.com

i have a list of companies that get listed in a tableView and the user can Open Each Company in to a detailViewController. When the rest of the companies details are shown i have a button i want the user to click if he or she likes that company. that data then gets stored in to a array of in the users data in a column called Liked in the users Class PFUser Current User.

when i click the Like Button Nothing happens i dont even get an error its like its not executing any code when the button is clicked

.h File

```
 PFObject *objectLike;
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender;
```

.m File

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

    [objectLike addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"Liked"];
    [objectLike saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"liked Company!");
            [self likedSuccess];
        }
        else {
            [self likedFail];
        }
    }];


}





//*******************************************************************************************
//methods to like selected image
//*******************************************************************************************

- (void) likeImage {

}

- (void) likedSuccess {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"You have succesfully liked the image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void) likedFail {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oooops!" message:@"There was an error when liking the image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

//*******************************************************************************************




//*******************************************************************************************
//methods to go to busineess website
//*******************************************************************************************
- (IBAction)WebAddressBtn:(id)sender {


    NSString *url = [self.exam objectForKey:@"website"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"website: %@",url);


}
//*******************************************************************************************
```

has anybody any ideas

the database id UserClass under the Key Liked which is an Array.

i dont see how this is a duplicate when its my app

Comment: It might sound silly, but make sure the IBAction is properly wired up.

Comment: Also, the linked question doesn't have an accepted answer, and the answers there have a grand total of one upvote, so it's not clear at all that this question is answered there. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you've failed to instantiate `objectLike`, so in your `LikeBtn:` method, you end up saving a nil object.

At the beginning of your `LikeBtn:` method, try adding:

PFObject *objectLike = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"WhateverYourClassNameIs"];

---

Edit: If updating the current user object, there's no need to use the `PFObject *objectLike`. Instead, update the `PFUser`. Try:

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

    [[PFUser currentUser] addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"Liked"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"liked Company!");
            [self likedSuccess];
        }
        else {
            [self likedFail];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Its A User class so i was lead to believe you didt need add the class if PFUser currentUser was in the code

Comment: @MikeJAspinall No that's not right... I've edited my answer to show what you do in the case of a user update.

Comment: Logistically though, I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing by updating the current PFUser. I assume you'd like to "like" other PFUsers... Perhaps add those "liked" PFUser's objects to the "Liked" array instead of adding the current PFUser's objectID to their own "Liked" array. P.S. You can't update another user's PFUser object.

Comment: no its just a simple list of companies they are not users. the users are the customers. the customer likes the companies. i want to save the array in the user class under a liked row array

Comment: @MikeJAspinall Then instead of adding the user's object id, add the company name or id to the liked column, ex. [[PFUser currentUser] addUniqueObject:@"Company name" forKey:@"Liked"];